# How can i get these html tags removed in my react app

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

`<figure class="image"><img scr="https://res.cloudinary.com/dfyhqttyxe/image/upload/v163126647133/zenith/uozgem6icqsrt3bitab6.jpg"></figure><p>The body</p>`

I am using editor in a ReactJS project where I need to render the editor content as React DOM html element on a next page.

All the contents written in the editor get rendered properly but I don't know how I can get the p , figure class and image tags removed. I just want the image url and the text .

If I attach any image url in the editor then the url appears as anchor tag as the src attribute of the img tag.

I need to remove that unwanted malformed anchor tag from the image src attribute and replace it will the image url.

Answer (score 0):

Its typo mistake

Correct tag is 'img' and try 'src' attribute instead of 'scr'